# constexpr and std::cout working on function but not in lambda

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr, cout

Why `constexpr` does not work with `std::cout`, but works with `printf`?

```
#include <iostream>
constexpr void f() { std::cout << ""; } //error
constexpr void g() { printf(""); } //ok
```

And why `std::cout` works with lambdas `constexpr`?

```
#include <iostream>
int main () {
    auto h = []() constexpr { std::cout << ""; }; //ok
}
```

Comment: Used gcc 9.1 on godbolt.org

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Technically, it doesn't work with any of them.

From [[dcl.constexr]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#5):

> For a constexpr function or constexpr constructor that is neither defaulted nor a template, if no argument values exist such that an invocation of the function or constructor could be an evaluated subexpression of a core constant expression, or, for a constructor, a constant initializer for some object ([basic.start.static]), **the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required**.

`f()` and `g()` are never constant expressions (neither `std::cout << x` nor `printf()` are constexpr functions), so the `constexpr` declaration is ill-formed. But the compiler isn't *required* to diagnose this (in this case, it may be easy, but in the general case... not so much). What you're seeing is that your compiler was able to diagnose one problem but not the other.

But they're both wrong.

Comment: Ugh stuff like this really grinds my gears. It seems _so_ arcane and hard to spot a bug like this. Meh to it all!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Practically speaking, it's really hard to generally diagnose "you marked this `constexpr` but it's impossible". So it'd be nice if compilers did, but like... it doesn't super matter. It definitely won't compile if you try to use it as a constant expression.

Comment: I'm complaining more about the language than about the compilers. It's utterly absurd that such "simple" code could be ill-formed in a manner that's so difficult for a compiler to diagnose, let alone for the programmer!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it's harder than hard. It's undecidable. In terms of Turing machines, this is closely related to the Halting Problem. _Meh to it all_ indeed.

Comment: @alterigel It's undecidable in general. As the question shows, a diagnostic may be issued in certain cases. But that's my point: some of the most allegedly simple newer features of the language are almost entirely academic in scope and nature (read: a C++ degree required to use them safely)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit come to think of it, a license to practice (advanced) C++ doesn't sound like a bad idea

Answer (score 8):

It doesn't. You need to use it to force a compile time error.

```
constexpr int a = f(), 0; // fails
constexpr int b = g(), 0; // fails
```

`constexpr` functions that never produce a constant expression are ill-formed; no diagnostic required. This means that compilers do a best effort check to see if that is the case, but your program already has an error either way. Seems like gcc can't see that `printf` is not a constant expression. [clang errors at the definition](https://godbolt.org/z/unRcDe).

Comment: Nice use of the comma operator :)

Comment: And what about the lambda object? Does it have to compile? By what I understood from your answer, no.

Comment: @JoãoPaulo It's the same there. It's an error, but compilers don't need to error out.

Comment: What is the significance of the comma(s) in the snippet above? A comma operator expression to enforce evaluation of the lhs?

Comment: @dfri I needed a way to force constant evaluation of the function and since it returns void, I can't assign it to a variable. So I used the comma operator inside the initializer of a constexpr variable so that the function is evaluated at compile time.