# MSVS community 2022 does not allow a constexpr with cout, but gcc does. Which is correct?

Tags: c++, function, constexpr

The following code does not compile on msvs community 2022, saying "error C3615: constexpr function 'logError' cannot result in a constant expression."

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


constexpr void logError(const std::string& error)
{
    std::cout << error << std::endl;
}

constexpr int sqrt(int x)
{
    if (std::is_constant_evaluated())
    {
       logError("Oh no, this is not constantly evaluated");
        return 30;

    }
    else
    {
        
        int result{};
        while (result * result <= x) ++result;
        return result - 1;
    }

}


int c = sqrt(9);
int main() { 
    
    
    std::cout << c;
    
    return 0; }
```

I compiled it on godbolt.org with "-std=c++23 -O2". The code compiled but the `else` block always runs. `logError` is never called with `if (std::is_constant_evaluated())` or `if (***!***std::is_constant_evaluated())`. Then which compiler is correct?

Comment: Do you think that `std::cout` is evaluated at compile time? How exactly would that work? If you change `c` to be a `constexpr int` you get an error, since `sqrt()` and `logError()` in it can not be evaluated at compile time ([live example](https://godbolt.org/z/4x1j6eMro)). The answer here [constexpr and std::cout working on function but not in lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56568230/constexpr-and-stdcout-working-on-function-but-not-in-lambda) states that your function is ill formed but the compiler is not required to diagnose it.

Comment: Thank you. MSVS is right in raising the error flag. And The reason is not because `cout` cannot be evaluated at compile-time but because `logError` is not a core constant expression function, according to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression, `bullet 3`

Comment: [Streaming to std::cout is not allowed in a constexpr context.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60841155/12002570) and  [Why can I call a non-constexpr function inside a constexpr function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22176777/why-can-i-call-a-non-constexpr-function-inside-a-constexpr-function)

Comment: @user12002570 And all the dupes are outdated. C++23 removes that rule.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat. I do not think so. Could you post a link to that?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat There was no need to reopen this question. You could have answered in any one of the dupes instead of reopening this.

Comment: @user12002570 I guess I could. None of the linked Q&As stood out to me as an obvious candidate to be a canonical dupe about this. I've picked [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77829977/2752075) now and posted an answer there too.

Comment: @user12002570 But I suggest we write the correct answer (on the dupe) first, and close second. Having to clean up an incorrectly closed question (picking the dupe most fit to be updated, posting an answer, removing other dupes, telling OP in the comments to go look at the dupe again) gets old fast.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I was not aware that the behavior changed in C++23. But since you pointed out that the behavior changed in C++23, you could/should've answered there directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before [c++23](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b23), there was a rule that if a `constexpr` function can never be executed at compile-time, the compilers *can* (but don't have to) complain even if that's not attempted.

Starting from C++23, [there's no such rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr#Notes) (the compilers are not allowed to complain).

Your `logError()` can't be executed at compile-time (because of `cout`), so it was illegal before C++23.

Since your `sqrt()` always tries to call a non-constexpr function from the `if (std::is_constant_evaluated())`, it will always cause a compilation error when used at compile-time. (And before C++23 it was illegal even when unusued, see above.)